# How to implement Wordpress-like Permalink

Tags: content-management-system, permalinks

I was thinking about a building a CMS, and I want to implement the wordpress-like permalink for my posts. How do I do that?
I mean, How do I define the custom url structure for my pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What language are you using? I'm assuming that you are thinking about PHP (given your reference to word press). You have a few options:

1. [Mod-Rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html)
2. [Router](http://query7.com/php-regular-expresssion-url-router)

In my opinion, the best option is to find a modern web framework that provides good routing functionality. Furthermore, look at modifying an existing CMS (many exist; you seem to have heard of word press).

Comment: I've already taken the case of customizing other CMSes in consideration. But I want to build it myself. Yes, I am working on PHP and yes, I'm very much familiar with other available CMSes.. I'll look in to the links you've provided. Thanks for the reply. :) And my actual intension is to learn how to build something like this. So, customizing is not one of my options. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend creating links that pass in a URL parameter such as ..."http://...PostID?123&CatID=232&..." so that when the person clicks on that particular link, you can parse the parameters in the URL, and get the exact post based on id, or even do further filtering by passing in other fields as needed.

Comment: If that was the case, there wasnt any need of this question. I want to define the url of my page.. Like you can do in wordpress. permalinks like http://abc.def/this-in-a-test-post ..

Comment: +1, the is nothing else required to provide a "permanent link"

Comment: @Bibhas: well, the type of permalinks that you refer to are really a feature that Apache provides. See answer from @Kevin. It seems that mod_rewrite is what you are looking for. But in the end, the mod_rewrite module simply transforms the url with params (as I mentioned to you) into a more user-friendly form such as http://abc.ed/link-to-my-post.html

Comment: I also guess so. :) for the reply though. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build the whole thing yourself, first understand what a [front controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) is, as it really addresses the underlying issue of how do you execute the same code for different URLs. With this understanding, there are two ways to attack the problem with this design pattern: URL rewriting or physical file generation.

**URL Rewriting**

With URL rewriting, you would need intercept the requested URL and send it onto your front controller. Typically this is accomplished at the web server level, although some application servers also act as web servers. With Apache, as others have posted, you would use mod_rewrite with a rule that looks something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /path/to/front/controller.ext [E=REQUEST_URI:%{REQUEST_URI},QSA,PT,NS]
```

With this rule, the path originally requested with be sent to the front controller as a variable called "REQUEST_URI". Note, I'm not sure the right syntax in PHP to access it. In the front controller hash (e.g. MD5) this value and use it to lookup the record from a database - take into account whatever hashing algorithm you use will produce duplicates. The hash is necessary if you allow URLs over whatever the max column size is in your database for varchar data, assuming you can't search on CLOBs.

**Physical File Generation**

Physical file generation would create a file that maps to the permanent URL you're imagining. So you'd write something that creates/renames the file at time it's posted. This removes the need for storing a hash and instead you place information about the post you want to serve inside that file (i.e. ID of the post) and pass that along to the front controller.

**Recommendation**

My preference is the URL rewriting approach, so you don't have to worry about writing dynamic code files out at runtime. That said, if you want something with less magic, or you're expecting *a lot* of requests, the physical file generation is the way to go because it's more obvious and requires the server to do less work.